# Underline function not working when position is absolute?

Tags: html, css

So I have a number of div's that i want underlined when they are hovered over, but it isn't working... I think it is because the position is set to be absolute but I need it to be like that? Please help me! Thankyou.

```css
#alltext {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 40px;
}
#Home {
  position: absolute;
  left: 550px;
  top: 30px;
}
#Products {
  position: absolute;
  left: 760px;
  top: 30px;
}
#Contact {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1020px;
  top: 30px;
}
a {
  color: white;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="alltext">
  <a href="index.html">
    <div id="Home">Home</div>
  </a>
  <a href="products.html">
    <div id="Products">Products</div>
  </a>
  <a href="contact.html">
    <div id="Contact">Contact</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the div inside a tag and use id inside the a tag....

Comment: first you change a text color and add a:hover div{text-decoration:underline;}

Comment: There are **much** better layout methods that `position:absolute`, you can read about them at [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your CSS as below.

```
a:hover div {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was going to say!

Answer (score 0):

Give the id to the `<a>` instead of the `<div>` and it will work as you need http://jsfiddle.net/2kh7bof7/

```
<a href="products.html" id="Products">
<div >Products</div>
</a>
```